# Normalizing Three Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I've run into a problem whilst normalizing my ERD—it's my first time doing this, so please bear with me.

I have three tables: `Users`; `Clients`; and `Messages`.  The cardinalities of the relationships between them is as follows—

1. **`Users:Clients` is *m*:*n***

   - Each user may have one or more clients.
   - Each client may have one or more users.
2. **`Users:Messages` is 1:*n***

   - Each user may send one or more messages.
   - Each message may only be sent by one client.
3. **`Clients:Messages` is 1:*n***

   - Each client may send one or more messages.
   - Each message may only be sent by one client.

As I understand it, I have to create an association table to resolve the *m*:*n* relationship between `Users` and `Clients`: let's say I call that table `user_client_list`. I understand the two PKs from `Users` and `Clients` are now going to be FKs in `user_client_list`, but **would its PK be a newly assigned ID counter**?

Also, when resolving the `Clients:Messages` and `Users:Messages` 1:*n* relationships, I would end up with the foreign keys `client_id` and `user_id` in the `Messages` table.  This seems a little bit odd to me—**is this proper practice**? Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Would the PK be a newly assigned ID counter?" - not necessary: the PK could be the compound of the two FKs e.g. `(user_id, client_id)`.

Comment: As for your second question, it might be more normal to combine users and clients into a single table with a column that flags which type each record is—then there would only be one FK from the messages table into that.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a pretty good idea. As for combining the two - that's what I was thinking - but figured I'd consult the community and see what works best.

Comment: One problem that you might encounter by adopting that approach would be that your `user_client_list` association table would then admit undesirable user-user and client-client relationships.  Protecting against such erroneous relationships would be part of your business logic (which could, if so desired, enforced within MySQL using triggers).

Comment: If I combined the users/clients table like suggested, and used the association table to resolved the M:M relationship, would the Messages table still point to the users table? Or would it at this point make sense to point messages to the associative table?

Comment: It would still point to the users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Upgrading my comments to an answer).

1. > As I understand it, I have to create an association table to resolve the *m*:*n* relationship between `Users` and `Clients`: let's say I call that table `user_client_list`. I understand the two PKs from `Users` and `Clients` are now going to be FKs in `user_client_list`, but **would its PK be a newly assigned ID counter**?

   You *could* create an ID counter in `user_client_list` and make it your PK, but that isn't usually necessary: unless the exact same relationship might exist multiple times, the PK could simply be the compound of the two FKs, e.g. `(user_id, client_id)`.
2. > Also, when resolving the `Clients:Messages` and `Users:Messages` 1:*n* relationships, I would end up with the foreign keys `client_id` and `user_id` in the `Messages` table.  This seems a little bit odd to me—**is this proper practice**? Am I missing something here?

   It would be more typical to combine `Users` and `Clients` into a single table, say `People`, with a column that flags whether a record represents a user or a client; then the `Messages` table would have only *one* FK into your new `People` table.

   One problem that you might encounter by adopting this approach would be that the `user_client_list` association table could then admit undesirable user-user and client-client relationships.  Protecting against such erroneous relationships would be part of your business logic that is usually implemented in your application code—but it could, if so desired, be enforced within MySQL using [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER checkInsertedRelationship
     BEFORE INSERT ON user_client_list  -- also do the same for updates
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF (SELECT type FROM People WHERE id = NEW.user_id) <> 'user' THEN
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 
           'The provided user_id does not represent a user type person';
       END IF;

       IF (SELECT type FROM People WHERE id = NEW.client_id) <> 'client' THEN
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT =
           'The provided client_id does not represent a client type person';
       END IF;
     END
   ;;
   ```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks for the detailed solution, and the additional concern with the business logic!